# Understanding why the Uniform distribution does not make a good prior.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, statistical-inference, bayesian

I'm reading a book about Bayesian statistics and in this book is being explained why the Uniform distribution does not make for a good prior. The following example is given:

**Example:** Suppose that $X|\Theta = \theta \sim \operatorname{Bin}(n,\theta)$ and take the uniform prior over the parameter set: $\Theta\sim \operatorname{Unif}(0,1)$. The prior is supposed to express ignorance about $\theta$.  However, if we are ignorant about $\theta$, we are ignorant about $\theta^2$ as well (for example).  If we define $\Psi= \Theta^2$, then $$f_\Psi(\psi) = f_\Theta(\sqrt{\psi})\dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{\psi}} = \dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{\psi}}\mathbb{1}_{(0,1)}(\psi)$$

this implies that small realisations of $\Psi$ are more probable than large realisations and we are no longer ignorant about $\Psi$.

**Question:** Why is $f_\Psi(\psi)$ the correct density function of $\psi$, the way it's given in the example? Isn't the density function of the uniform distribution supposed to be a constant? I understand why the uniform distribution would not work if this is in fact the correct density, I don't know why it is though.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Question:** Why is $f_\Psi(\psi)$ the correct density function of $\psi$, the way it's given in the example? Isn't the density function of the uniform distribution supposed to be a constant?

Indeed, but it is $\Theta$ that is supposedly uniformly distributed, not $\Theta^2$, and we have definied $\Psi$ as being $\Theta^2$.   So by the chain rule we have: $$\begin{split}f_\Psi(\psi) &=\left\lvert\dfrac{\partial~\mathsf P(\Theta^2\leqslant \psi)}{\partial~\psi\hspace{9.5ex}}\right\rvert\\[1ex] &= \left\lvert\dfrac{\partial~F_\Theta(\surd \psi)}{\partial~\psi\hspace{7.5ex}}\right\rvert \\[1ex] &=\left\lvert\dfrac{\partial~\surd \psi}{\partial~\psi~~~~}\right\rvert~ f_\Theta(\surd\psi)\\[1ex] & = \dfrac 1{2\surd\psi}~\mathbf 1_{(0;1)}(\psi)\end{split}$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer! However, why does one take the derivative here?

Comment: It is the chain rule: $[f\circ g]' = g' \cdot [f'\circ g] $

Comment: Sorry, I think my question wasn't clear enough. I understand that if you want to take the derivative of $f$ to $\psi$, you get the given results using the chain rule. However, why is the derivative taken in the first place? Is there a rule/theorem that says that if $\psi = \theta^2$ then the density function $f(\psi)$, is equal to the derivative of $f(\theta)$ w.r.t. $\theta$?

Comment: This is an application of the general change of variables formula. -- that is, the formula that lets us figure out the distribution of $g(X)$ for some function $g$ and random variable $X$ when we know the distribution of $X$. See [Wikipedia.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function#Dependent_variables_and_change_of_variables).

Comment: A probability density function is the unsigned derivative of the cumulative distribution function.$$f_{\Theta^2}(\psi) = \left\lvert\dfrac{\partial \mathsf P(\Theta^2\leqslant \psi)}{\partial \psi}\right\rvert$$